# Remove Persistant Apps from Doc

Tags: dock

Apple Podcast and TV keep adding themselves back to by dock after I have removed them each reboot.

I have been searching around and have seen multiple posts about this issue, but most of them are old and not working for me (such as [Permanently remove icons from Dock](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227272/permanently-remove-icons-from-dock?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Removing Dock Items](https://community.jamf.com/t5/jamf-pro/removing-dock-items/m-p/193186), [How to stop maps photos and ibooks from loading in dock on startup](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225196/how-to-stop-maps-photos-and-ibooks-from-loading-in-dock-on-startup?rq=1) etc)

Most of the posts resolve around updating the defaults.plist for the dock and then resetting it. However I was unable to change the plist (/System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/defaults.plist) as it is now in the Dock app which is on a read-only drive.

I have tried editing /Users/[username]/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist but it reverts every restart.

Is there anyway to stop these from being added back to the dock in Big Sur?

Comment: I am running BigSur and both of those Apps are not appearing in my dock. Maybe a bug?

Comment: Do you use these two apps at all?

Comment: What version of macOS are you running on your Mac?

Comment: I have never used these apps and they do not start up when I reboot, they are just added back to my dock. I am on version 11.6, but I also had this issue on Catalina before I upgraded.

Comment: Have you tried deleting com.apple.dock.plist, rebooting, then removing the 2 items from dock, rebooting again? Have you checked ~/Library/LaunchAgents for any startup icons that could result in this behaviour? Where in the dock do the items appear?