# How to prevent uTorrent from autolaunching at startup?

Tags: macos, torrent

When I start my Mac each time I am faced with uTorrent opening automatically. I went to Share Preferences -> User -> LoginApp to check if this app is chosen, but no...

So how to remove this app from autolaunch?

Comment: See the answers to this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/81821/178418

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the web app version - see this answer - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/394352/5472

Those still using the app, this guide will solve the problem:
[Stop uTorrent from Opening at Startup with Mac OSX - wikihow Instructions](http://www.wikihow.com/Stop-uTorrent-from-Opening-at-Startup-with-Mac-OS-X)

The steps from the link are:

1. Open uTorrent
2. Click on uTorrent beside the "apple" and click Preferences
3. Click on General
4. Uncheck the box. Under Program Startup there are two options. Uncheck the second one that says Start uTorrent when Mac starts up

This stops the uTorrent app launch the next startup.

Comment: this answer is no longer relevant. There is no Preferences in the utorrent web app as of today.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on uTorrent web, @davka's method doesn't work. Please follow below steps in case of uTorrent web.

1. Start uTorrent web
2. Open URL http://127.0.0.1:19575/gui/index.html (or) uTorrent home page
3. Go to the settings icon
4. Setting pop up will open
5. Under "System" header, **uncheck** the option "Start μTorrent Web when computer starts"

Done!!

[image: screenshot turn off uTorrent web autostart]